# workflowAssociation not displaying workflow

Tags: list, development, workflow, event-handlers

I have created a feature. In the FeatureActivated event I am creating some lists. I am then trying to attach a custom workflow to one of the created lists. However when I do this the workflow history list that I create disappears.

Here is the code that associates the workflow to the list.

```
var workflowAssociation = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListAssociation(workflowTemplate[id], "Submit For Approval", taskList, historyList);
                workflowAssociation.AllowManual = true;
                workflowAssociation.AutoStartChange = false;
                workflowAssociation.AutoStartCreate = false;
                underApprovalList.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workflowAssociation);
                workflowAssociation.Enabled = true;
```

Where:

- workflowTemplate[id] is web.WorkflowTemplates[id of template]
- taskList non null splist created with  SPListTemplateType.Tasks
- historyList non null splist created with WorkflowHistory
- underApprovalListnon null splist of SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary type

When I comment this code out of the event the historyList is created. When I do not comment it out it is not.

**Update**

The history list is there if you navigate by URl rather than look for it. So the problem seems to be that the workflowAssociation is not working...

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Workflow history is not reliable (more so if you have multiple independent workflows active against a specific list).

One way to avoid that problem is to consider creating a custom list to store all of your audit type information.